# Changing ObservableCollection Value throws read only error

Tags: c#

I have an ObservableCollection defined as

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, double>> comboBoxSelections 
{ 
 get; 
 set; 
}
```

later on in my code I need to iterate the collection and change some values only but keep the same key. I've tried the following

```
        for (int i = 0; i < comboBoxSelections.Count ; i++)
        {
            comboBoxSelections[i].Value = SomeDoubleValue;
        }
```

but this gives error `Property or indexer 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,double>.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Can someone please explain why I get the error and how to allow updates to the `ObservableCollection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `ObservableCollection<T>` that is read-only, it's the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, because the latter is a `struct`. It is a good design practice for `struct`s to be immutable.

The correct way to update your collection is

```
comboBoxSelections[i] =
    new KeyValuePair<string, double>(comboBoxSelections[i].Key, someDoubleValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message is clear. The `Value` property of `KeyValuePair` is read only. I cannot give detailed answer for second part of the question, but quick googling gives:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx